# Automapper map source properties to some destination properties

Tags: c#, inheritance, .net-core, automapper

When create a map for a class destination based on an interface and source class based on another class, automapper omit the properties that's new on the destination class, mapped with cutom configuration (using ForMember and MapFrom).

The source class and Source base Class:

```
public class SourceDictionary: SourceBaseDictionary
{
    public SourceDictionary(int id, string code, string name);
}

public class SourceBaseDictionary: ISourceDictionary
{
    public SourceBaseDictionary();

    public int Id { get; protected internal set; }
    public string Code { get; protected internal set; }
    public string Name { get; protected internal set; }
}
```

The destination Class:

```
public class DestinationDictionary:IDestinationDictionary
{
    public int Id { get; set ; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    string Label { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

My configuration for Automapper:

```
 public class AutoMapperDictionary : Profile
 {
     public AutoMapperDictionary()
     {
        CreateMap<SourceDictionary, DestinationDictionary>()
            .ForMember(vm => vm.Value, map => map.MapFrom(m => m.Id))
            .ForMember(vm => vm.Label, map => map.MapFrom(m => m.Name));
     }
 }
```

And That's why I get now:

```
 {
    "id": 1,
    "value": 0,
    "code": "codeTest",
    "label": null,
    "name": "nameTest"
  }
```

Why the properties value and label don't have the same value that id and name?

**EDIT (with extra info)**

In my startup before services.AddMvc() i get:

```
services.AddAutoMapper();
Mapper.Initialize(x =>
{
     x.AddProfile(new AutoMapperDictionary());
     x.ValidateInlineMaps = false;
});
```

When i use the map function:

```
var queryResult = await conn.QueryAsync<SourceDictionary>(query);
var newDestinationDictionaryList = queryResult.ToList().Select(req => Mapper.Map<DestinationDictionary>(req))
```

When I comment the line "x.ValidateInlineMaps = false" I got the exception:

> AutoMapperConfigurationException ...
>    Unmapped members were found....
>    Unmapped properties:
>       Value
>       Label

Comment: Check [the execution plan](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Understanding-your-mapping.html).

Comment: How you configured the AutoMapper in the Startup.cs file? and How you invoke the AutoMapper class to transform the source object into the destination object?

Comment: thank you for the help!!
I added the extra info on the main post.

Comment: You created the Map properly between source and destination object but there are lots of syntax error in the shared code! If it is a demo project, just update your code in GitHub repository and share the link. Unless you share the complete code it is tough to identify the exact problem of this issue.